# Possible math.ceil() bug

Tags: python

On Windows 7 Python 3.2, the following:

```
print(int(math.ceil(24/10)))
```

gives me '3' as expected.

On Windows Server with Active Python 2.5, it gives me '2'.

What is the issue here and how can I solve it?

Here's my original code:

```
number_of_pages = int(math.ceil(number_of_rows/number_of_rows_per_page))
```

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: I would guess this isn't a bug in python, but in a lower level.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python 2.x uses truncating disivion, so the answer to `24/10` is 2. The `ceil` of 2 is still 2.

The fix is to convert one of the operands to float:

```
print(int(math.ceil(24.0/10)))
```

Comment: Does this cause a lot of confusion?

Comment: If you don't need the int division behavior for e.g. backwards compatibility, you can `from __future__ import division` and have the reasonable semantics when `1/2 = 0.5`.

Comment: In 3.x (and in fact, as far back as 2.2), Python provides a dedicated syntax for truncating division (a//b). In other words, math.ceil(24//10) should be 2 in both versions.

Comment: @Baz, only the first time it happens to you. Most languages define the division of two integers to be an integer, so you get used to it fast.

Comment: @jpm, I had no idea `//` went that far back, thanks for the info.

Comment: I knew C++ was like that but not Python... its also easy to forget this, thats why I'm glad future python versions don't behave in this fashion.  from __future__ import division causes 4/10 to produce 0.4, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A quick perusal of programming languages finds that integer divided by integer returns

**an integer**

- python 2
- java
- c++
- c
- c#
- ruby
- ocaml
- f#
- go
- fortran

**floating point** (asterisk means that there is alternative syntax to return an integer)

- python 3*
- javascript
- php
- perl*
- dart*
- vbscript
- vb.net*
- erlang*
- pascal*

**something else**

- clojure (returns a ratio if it cannot return an integer)

Python's choice to change the semantics of the division operator was [quite controversial](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) at the time.  Returning an integer often surprises beginning programmers and mathematicians, however, experienced programmers often feel the same way when they find that dividing two integers can return floating point.

Comment: I like this idea of using ratios to store floats. Has it been considered for python?

Comment: There is `Fraction` in the `fractions` module.  But you almost never need it.  There is also `Decimal` in the `decimal` module which acts as a friendlier floating point.  These datatypes are inherently slower than integers and floating point.  They are also a tad unwieldy.  Use as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `print(int(math.ceil(24/10.0)))` , it will return the correct value. As has been pointed, in Python 2.5 the expression `24/10` evaluates to `2`, because it's performing an integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is here http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/.